# Combine arrays with specific shape using numpy

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to mimic the combination of the `aa` and `bb` arrays shown below using `zip()` within a `for` block:

```
import numpy as np

aa = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (3, 566))
bb = np.random.uniform(0., 1., (3, 566))

cc = []
for a, b in list(zip(list(zip(*aa)), list(zip(*bb)))):
    cc.append(list(zip(*[a, b])))
cc = np.array(cc)

print(cc.shape)
(566, 3, 2)
```

I've tried `vstack`, `hstack`, `column_stack`, all of them combined with `.reshape()` to no avail. Obviously, not only the final shape should be equal, but the array itself too.

What is the proper `numpy` way to do this?

Comment: Another variation on `stack`: np.stack([aa,bb],1).transpose(2,0,1)`.  This gets the (3,2) order right, and then transposes the 566 to the start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can transpose `aa` and `bb` and then use [`numpy.dstack`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.dstack.html)(*stack arrays along third axis*), i.e. `np.dstack([aa.T, bb.T])`:

```
np.dstack([aa.T, bb.T]).shape
# (566, 3, 2)

(np.dstack([aa.T, bb.T]) == cc).all()
# True
```

Or use `np.stack(..., axis=-1)`:

```
(np.stack([aa.T, bb.T], axis=-1) == cc).all()
# True
```